# How to deploy Parcel.js project to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, parceljs

I have a project bundled with parcel.js bundler. I want to deploy it to firebase.

I'm ready to deploy the website but i'm confused as to what files i am deploying to firebase. I do understand that parcel.js provides a dist folder for production, but i dont know if i have to upload the entire files of the project including the dist folder or just the dist folder.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're uploading it to any hosting site actually, you would just upload the contents of the dist folder. The other folders are not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for that clarification Maria. I know it's a bit of a noob question, but it was confusing me.